# Push Notification for Http Websites

Tags: http, firebase, push-notification, service-worker

I have implemented web push using Firebase using Service-workers (which works only for https website). I want to use web push notification for http website.
I have read that it is possible to implement the web push for http website using some tweaks like subscribing to any third party.
Two questions I want to ask:
a) Is it possible to achieve the same without using any third party library?
b) How can I achieve the same behaviour for my website?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

a) Is it possible to achieve the same without using any third party library?

From the [developer guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/): **No**, During development you'll be able to use service worker through localhost. but to deploy it **you need HTTPS**, the site registering the service worker must on on HTTPS and the service worker, which has to be on the same origin, will be served over HTTPS as a result. For security reasons. Having modified network requests, wide open to man in the middle attacks would be really bad

b) if you need web push notifications and you don't have an SSL take a look at Pushpad Express https://pushpad.xyz/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Can you please help me in suggesting how https://pushpad.xyz/ achieve it. If I want to replicate the same in my js file. How can I achieve it.?

Comment: if you want to write your own service-worker js file you need HTTPS setup on your server and pushpad can't help you because it require to use pushpad-service-worker js file.

Comment: Can you please explain https server setup on my server. 
I am having my website on https and one on http..
What changes do I need to make in my files to server push notification over http client.

Comment: you must move your http website to https.

Comment: You can get a free SSL cert at https://letsencrypt.org/ or use Firebase or Heroku to host your website and point the domain to those services to get the free SSL

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually we have our own client code for sending and scheduling notification. As far as I have seen the integration code of https://pushpad.xyz/ with my code, they provide their own module for subscribing, scheduling and sending notifications.
My problem is, I dont want to subscribe to their notification panel. What my requirement is, currently our notification has been integrated with firebase and utilizing service worker for push notifications. 
Now, requirement is to get push notification even when the website is http.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can't. because service-worker require https on production